# Coding difference between tracking and staging files

Tags: indexing, libgit2

With libgit2 API, is there any difference between 'adding' a file for tracking, or adding a modified file to the staging area?

This is the code I am currently using to stage tracked files which are modified:

```
int giterror = git_repository_index( &index, open_repo );
if( giterror != 0 )
{
    return giterror;
}

//  Refresh the index from disk to load the entries that may already be staged
giterror = git_index_read( index );
if( giterror != 0 )
{
    git_index_free( index );

    return giterror;
}


giterror = git_index_add_bypath( index, relativeFilePath );
if( giterror != 0 )
{
    git_index_free( index );

    return giterror;
}


// write updated index to disk - aka staging area
giterror = git_index_write( index );
if( giterror != 0 )
{
    git_index_free( index );

    return giterror;
}


// write the index of changes to a tree
git_oid rootTreetOID;
giterror = git_index_write_tree( &rootTreetOID, index );
if( giterror != 0 )
{
    git_index_free( index );

    return giterror;
}
```

Should I use the same code to add an untracked file to the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should.

`git_index_add_bypath()` documentation states that this method should be used when one is willing to *"Add or update an index entry from a file on disk"*.

This method is able to

- add an untracked file to the index
- stage the modification of a file